# Heidi Sql Session Manager Not Working Ubuntu 14.04 with Wine

Tags: ubuntu, wine, heidisql

I had installed Wine in Ubuntu and Downloaded Heidi Sql 9.4 and 9.0 from Original Website.

After successfull installation of Heidi Sql,
The Session Manager had started and it was asking for Connection Details.

After Typing all the Localhost Connection Details.

-> If those details are wrong. Its reporting that **Connection Failed**.

-> If the details are right. Its doing nothing.
I mean, I cannot see the next screen with correct connection details.

I`m stuck here. Please Help me.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should post the *exact* error message, as I highly guess "Connection failed" is not what Heidi reports. Even if it's a longer message, don't hide messages which other users need in order to help you.

Comment: Which database you try to connect - MySQL, PostgreSQL,...? Did you enter a database name below the credentials?